# Where can I see the number of visitors over the past 24 hours in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I can see past days:

[image]

and past 30 min:

[image]

But where can I see the number of visitors over the past 24 hours in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, one cannot view the number of visitors over the past 24 hours in Google Analytics (unlike for some other sites owned by Google, such as YouTube).